# Starting puma (with nginx) on server boot using environment variables, rails 4.1.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, puma

I'm trying to use nginx and puma on my web server (a fresh install on AWS), and am getting stuck on environment variables.

Specifically, my puma upstart - https://github.com/puma/puma/tree/master/tools/jungle/upstart - and config file (config/puma.rb) both seem to ignore my "RAILS_ENV" variable, even though all users see them when I do echo "$ENV_VAR" as both my base user (rails) and as root.

In the runcmd section of my cloud-init, I just have:

```
- echo "RAILS_ENV=staging" >> /etc/profile
- echo "RAILS_ENV=staging" >> /etc/environment
```

to set this variables, but this doesn't seem to actually work. What is the proper way to set environment variables so my rails application can use them?

For instance, in my config/puma.rb, I have

```
rails_env = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'production'
environment rails_env
```

but it always goes to production, ignoring the 'staging' setting of my environment variable. How should I fix this?

Comment: Did you figure this out?